# Не получается авторизоваться через requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте через requests. Делаю POST-запрос, раньше он возвращал код ответа 302 и html страницу, на которую перенаправлял запрос. Теперь Код приходит 200 и никакого html. В чем может быть проблема?

На всякий случай код:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
auth = {
        'email': 'kxr94758@molms.com',
        'password': 'ANwgr3bAfgg',
        'option': 'email' }

r = session.post('https://www.sportmaster.ru/user/session/login.do?continue=https://www.sportmaster.ru/user/profile/bonus.do', data=auth)
print(r.status_code) # -->> 200
print(r.text) # -->> тут пусто
```

Comment: Ну смотрите запросы, как мы можем вам помочь. Вы не предоставили ни ссылки на сайт, ни данных для авторизации. Ну а так по коду все правильно.

Comment: Поправил вопрос, добавил данные для запроса

Comment: Авторизация вообще по другому адресу идет у спортмастера

Comment: https://sportmaster.api.useinsider.com/ajax.php?t=saveFormResult

Comment: И кроме логина и пароля там еще 20 лишних параметров передается

Comment: Как вы нашли этот адрес, расскажите пожалуйста, в запросах я его не нашел. И какие там еще параметры, где их посмотреть? Раньше работало так, как в моем примере.

Comment: Заходите на сайт, переходите в авторизацию. Затем в браузере переходите в режим разработчика на вкладку сеть, затем вводите свои регистрационные данные и нажимаете отправить и отслеживайте какой запрос ушел, и смотрите в параметрах, какие данные ушли. Страница, откуда я смотрел https://www.sportmaster.ru/user/session/login.do

Comment: Тот запрос, про который вы говорите, вроде просто сохраняет данные в форме авторизации, но это не сама авторизация, попробуйте ввести данные, но кнопку не нажимать, запрос будет отправляться на каждый введенный символ после небольшой задержки. Авторизация идет POST запросом на адрес, который в моем примере, только в браузере он отдает код 302, а через requests - 200. И дальнейший переход по страницам в сессии, возвращает html код страницы авторизации.

Comment: В любом случае без нормальных данных авторизаций не понятно. У вас почта не подтверждена

Comment: дак данные валидны, чтоб зайти на аккаунт не обязательно подтверждать почту, попробуйте зайти